can not publish library after upgrade gradle version 8.4 in kotlin
I upgraded my kotlin and android gradle plugin versions as follows and I got this error as follows when I try to publish library
ERROR
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:


Execution failed for task
':sdk:publishXXX-saas-sdkPublicationToMavenLocalRepository'.

Failed to publish publication 'xxx-saas-sdk' to repository 'MavenLocal'
Invalid publication 'xxx-saas-sdk': multiple artifacts with the identical extension and classifier ('jar', 'sources').


kotlin version: 1.9.0
android gradle version: 8.4
build.gradle.kts(project)
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `maven-publish`
    id("com.android.application") version "8.3.0" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.3.0" apply false
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}


buildscript{
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.20")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2")
    }
}

gradle.wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip

build.gradle.kts(sdk)
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("maven-publish")
}

android {
   ...
}
tasks.register("sourcesJar", Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from(android.sourceSets["main"].java.srcDirs) {
        include("xxx/builder/**")
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>("xxx-saas-sdk") {
                from(components["prodRelease"])
                groupId = "com.myProject
                artifactId = "saas"
                version = "1.0.0"

                pom {
                    name.set("MyProjectSaaSSDK")
                }

                artifact(tasks["sourcesJar"])

                repositories {
                    mavenLocal()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ....
}

I searched on the internet but I couldn't implemented them to my project because I couldn't understand how to implement to my project.
I cannot access sdk library classes or something when I remove artifact(tasks["sourcesJar"]) from build.gradle.kts (sdk)
